# Email based interface for reserving resources in MS Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, interop, reserved

Is there a way to manage reservations of Outlook resources like resource1@example.com entirely through email? I know that it is easily managed through Outlook by creating new Appointments and Meetings and then inviting the resource's email address.

These features look a lot like sending an email though. Is there a way to skip Outlook entirely and reserve resources using only regular email? Maybe some kind of formatted HTML or XML in the message body?

This would allow us to book resources from anywhere, like from Linux boxes without Outlook, workflows in SharePoint, or even in browser in ymail or gmail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you configure the mailbox to accept the meeting requests automatically. A meeting request is nothing but an iCal invitation.

Comment: It already seems to have some kind of auto-accept functionality. It will book the resource unless it is already taken. But the question is how to do that through an email? I only know how to do it through the special Appointment form in Outlook.

Comment: You would need to send a message with the content type of "text/calendar; method=REQUEST". The MIME body must be a single MIME part with the iCal data.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look into this. Is it the same for editing and cancelling appointments?

Comment: Yes, use method=REQUEST for new/existing appointments and method=-CANCEL for the cancelations.

Comment: Okay, I think I'm most of the way there. How would I go about actually putting these settings into the email? Searching for this has yielded few results, and most of them actually say you can't do this from Yahoo/Google mail...

Comment: If you want to send raw MIME, you have no choice but you use SMTP.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to figure this bit out but couldn't get it. Could you tell me how I might do this from SharePoint workflows? Or maybe from Yahoo?

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Constructing the MIME message? Deciding which SMTP component to use? Or something different?

Comment: I don't actually know what any of this is. I've read up on what MIME and SMTP are, but it isn't helping me compose a simple message. Is there a good resource that I can use to learn it? Google is failing me. I've found stuff about making MIME messages programmatically, but that is way beyond what I'm trying to do. I'm looking for an end user solution. Does the MIME message just go into the body of the email? Is it an attachment?

Comment: There is no end user solution, you would actually need to write code to do this.

Comment: That's extremely unfortunate. Thanks for your help though, I learned some interesting things.